LTSpice Boost Converter Simulation
I'm very new to electrical engineering and am doing a boost converter project to expose myself to the topic. I've designed a boost converter that is supposed to take 3V input to 5V output, 500mA max current draw, at 62.5kHz switching frequency.
I'm not sure why my step up is basically negligible for the output. Here are my calculations for component selection, plus a circuit I drew. I suspect it has something to do with my mosfet selection but not experienced enough to know why. I chose a IRFZ44N because of its (relatively?) low Rds (17.5mOhm) and its Vgs(min) is 2.0V, which should work for 3V input. Below is the output from LTSpice. The load resistance is an arbitrarily chosen resistance (I simulated it to find the ideal resistance for max efficiency) but it seems like the output is about the same no matter what I choose, so I'm not sure if that's the issue.   

V2 voltage (3V) is too low to turn on the MOSFET. Also why you do not use a 1n or 16u to see the time instead you are using 1e-9, 16e-6?

Vto parameter for the IRFZ44N model within LTspice is 4.

Look at the data sheet and see that the gate source threshold voltage could be as high as 4 volts: -

Even then you are only guaranteed a drain current of 250 μA. You need to choose a more appropriate MOSFET for this low voltage application or use a MOSFET driver that can magnify the drive voltage.
Your calculations seem about right BTW.
